# Railscast #111 uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railscasts

I followed the episode 111 on Railscast.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised?view=asciicast

I modifed the model names but the other stuff is basically the same. I only want to show you the code where my error appears:
**Controller:**

```
   def suche
     @search = Search.find(params[:id])
   end
```

**Model:**

```
  class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ausdruck, :keyword, :maximum, :minimum, :rund, :zeitraum

   def patients
@patients ||= find_patients
   end

   private

   def find_patients
     patients = Patients.order(:vorname)
     patients = patients.where("vorname like ?", "%#{keyword}%") if keyword.present?
     patients
   end
 end
```

And my **view**:

```
<%= @search.patients.each do |f| %>
  <%= f %>
<% end %>
```

Somehow i get this **error:**

```
NameError in Patients#suche

Showing C:/geburtstag/app/app/views/patients/suche.html.erb where line #1 raised:

uninitialized constant Search::Patients
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= @search.patients.each do |f| %>
```

PATient model:

```
 class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :drucken, :extraanrede, :extratext, :geburtsdatum, :geschlecht,:nachname, :vorname
 scope :drucken, where(:drucken => true)
 end
```

Comment: Could you show us you Patient model, together with its file name and file location?

Comment: I updated my question with the patient model! Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the name of the file of your patient model? Is it in app/models folder?

Comment: Never mind, Found an error!

Comment: Yes its in the models folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class name in rails are singular, so you want

```
Patient.order(:vorname)
```

in your find_patients method.

Comment: Oh menn!! Thanks!! I had tomatos on my eyes!